# How to grep MATLAB (OS X) command line output?

Tags: matlab

From the MATLAB command line (OS X version), how can one grep the output so as to limit the returned information?

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB doesn't have inbuilt grep. If you don't want to use something like [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9647-grep--a-pedestrian--very-fast-grep-utility), you can stream the output into a variable, and use strfind to look for your desired pattern.